# pop up numeric keypad in NavigationWindow WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationwindow

I need to get numeric input from user in a WPF application runs on a touch screen device. The idea is to have a numeric keypad pops up when the `TextBox` is focused.

I am using `NavigationWindow`, and actually have already built a numeric keypad as a `Page`. However, I don't want to navigate user to a `new Page()`, because it would be nice to stay on the current page with its data.

Anyidea for the "pop up" numeric keypad in a NavigationWindow WPF app? Thanks!

Comment: How about just displaying the `Page` in a [`Frame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx)? You can locate the `Frame` anywhere you want on the current `Page`.

Comment: Thanks! I am now using your suggestion, but encountered a new problem. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297401/wpf-how-to-access-mainpage-elements-from-popup-page) if interested :)

Comment: If that solved your problem, I'll add it as an answer so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `NavigationWindow`, you can also display a `Page` using the [`Frame` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx). The `Frame` can be any size and you can locate it anywhere you want on the current Page. From the linked page on MSDN:

> Frame is a content control that provides the ability to navigate to and display content. Frame can be hosted within other content, as with other controls and elements.