# WPF how to access MainPage elements from Popup Page

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF app that needs numeric input from user. I am using NavigationWindow and have built a `Page` that contains a numeric keypad. The app needs numeric input more than once. Inspired by [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39c285ae-cc5a-4edb-b482-d6382a71a82a/frame-popup-opening-and-closing?forum=wpf), I want to put numeric `Page` inside a `Frame` inside a `Popup` as follows:

```
<Grid Name="mainDisplay">
    <Popup Name="popupDialog" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=aInputBox Placement="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Frame Source="MyNumpad.xaml"/>
            <Button Click="OK_Outside_Click">Ok_Outside_Numpad</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
// invalid comment and other stuff in grid....
</Grid>
```

When the "Ok_Outside_Numpad" `Button` is clicked, the numpad disappears and the main page is re-enabled. Code as follows:

```
private void OK_Outside_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popupDialog.IsOpen = false;
    mainDisplay.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Two questions:

1. There is already an "OK" button *inside* `MyNumpad.xaml`. Is it possible to access the `mainDisplay` and `popupDialog` clicking `Ok_Inside_Numpad` button? How can I pass variables to
   `MyNumpad` constructor?
2. How to get the user numeric input when `MyNumpad` exits?

Thanks! Note that I am new to WPF, not sure if my approach is any good. Any idea is welcomed!

Comment: Ideally, you should do this with bindings, but if you want to do it in the code-behind, it would be easier to have your `mainDisplay` toggle its own state based on the popup's `Opened` and `Closed` events than to make the content hosted within the popup responsible for UI elements it should know nothing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) the `View`s (NavigationWindow and MyNumpad.xaml) to a `ViewModel` (or several ViewModels). With data binding, you simply set a value to false to close the Popup (since the Popup's IsOpen property is bound to that value). It does not matter where a control resides since you don't need to manipulate controls in your code.

But before reading that long article and begin to learn MVVM, you can make some modification to your code to make it work.

You can't access MainPage elements from the hosted page, as the hosted page has no reference to the MainPage. As you have thought about, you can pass MainPage to the constructor of `MyNumpad` (do it in code, and remember to modify MyNumpad's constructor).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyNumpad numpad = new MyNumpad(this);
    frame1.Navigate(numpad);
}
```

Then you can access MainPage elements from the Popup Page.

But it is easier to add a Click event handler to the Popup's button, because the event handler is defined inside MainWindow, it has access to all controls in MainWindow. (Remember to delete the event handler defined inside MyNumpad.)

```
string strNumber;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyNumpad numpad = new MyNumpad();
    numpad.button1.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(
        (s, e) => 
        {
            //suppose there is a TextBox in the page to accept user input
            strNumber = numpad.InputTextBox.Text; 
            popupDialog.IsOpen = false;
            mainDisplay.IsEnabled = true; 
        }), false);
    frame1.Navigate(numpad);
}
```

Comment: thanks, just what i needed! I chose to add a Click event handler to the Popup's ConfirmButton, since it's used at multiple locations and each requires a different confirm behavior. btw, in what kind of project it is worthwhile to use MVVM? in other words, when can one get by *decently* without it, if possible?